# How to create custom email template, to approve/reject through mail reply?

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process

I have a requirement where approver have to **approve** or **reject** or **Approve Under condition** the opportunity record through mail reply. Means,

If approver want to approve the record under condition, he can do this by replying **Approve Under condition** through mail.

By sales force standard functionality  we can only **Approve** or **reject** and **not Approve** under conditions.

Could any one please guide me to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Where does the condition get saved?

Comment: We have custom pick list status where approve under condition is one of the option. Once approver approves the record by approve under condition. Status should get changed to Approved Under condition.

Comment: trying to force fit this requirement into SFDC Approval Processes is going to be hard as there are many constraints - especially the approve-by-email feature which is extremely limited. You might want to consider creating an alternate approval process workflow via Process Builder + Inbound Email Services